# CLI/C++ and C#: How to capture C++ exceptions in Release Mode

Tags: c#, c++, exception

I have this problem:

From `Managed C++`, I use a `C#` `DLL` where I register a `delegate` defined in `Managed C++`. The `C#` library executes this `delegate` and inside it, it raises a `native exception`. In **Debug** mode the `try/catch` is executed but in **Release** mode it doesn't. But in the same scenario, if the exception is thrown by 100% managed code, I can catch it.

This is the code that I am using:

`Managed C++`:

```
class CNativeClass
{
    public:
      int one;
}

// This C method is registred like Delegate in C#
void OnMsgReceived(ManagedObjectInCSharp^ obj)
{
    CNativeClass* pelota;
    pelota->one = 0; // <-- This procude a NullPointerException
    Console::WriteLine(L"OnMsgReceived");
}
```

My `C#` execute this `delegate` with a `try/catch`. In **Debug** it is OK but in **Release**, it isn't.

```
//But if I defined the method like this:
void OnMsgReceived(ManagedObjectInCSharp^ obj)
{
    try  
    {
        CNativeClass* pelota;
        pelota->one = 0; // <-- This procude a NullPointerException
        Console::WriteLine(L"OnMsgReceived");
    }
    catch(const char* str)
    {
    }
}
```

My `C#` capture the exception in release mode.

Comment: Don't catch exceptions like that, fix the bug instead.  You cannot otherwise catch access violations with a C++ catch, catch (Exception^ ex) will catch-em-all.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that is a client who program this method and the app don`t crash! I try with catch(Exception^ex) inside the method and the exception not catched!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, perhaps this is a long shot, but try adding this attribute to your C# method:

```
[System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx

Comment: Thanks! But not supported in NET 3.5 and the problema continue... it´s very strange.